# How to completely disable or hide Back button in QWizard?

Tags: qt, qt4, wizard

I want to disable or hide Back button in QWizard dialog. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked at Qt's sources and found out that it's possible to hide Back button by creating custom button layout and ommiting Back button in the list:

```
  QList<QWizard::WizardButton> button_layout;
  button_layout << QWizard::HelpButton << QWizard::Stretch <<
                   QWizard::NextButton << QWizard::CustomButton1 <<
                   QWizard::CancelButton;
  this->setButtonLayout(button_layout);
```

I hope this will save some time to somebody.

P.S.

AFAIU to avoid using QTimer it is needed to modify QWizard source code. The easies way will be to add a virtual function 
virtual void buttonsUpdated();
and call it from the end of QWizard's:
void QWizardPrivate::_q_updateButtonStates()
Then reimplement this buttonsUpdated() in your QWizard sublass and disable Back button there.

Comment: you can take QWizard::BackButton at anytime with `QWizrad::button ( WizardButton which ) const` and hide/disable it at anytime

Comment: did you check it yourself? I checked it on 4.7.4 and it didn't work that simple

Answer (score 5):

Calling

```
QWizard::button(QWizard::BackButton).hide()
```

in

```
QWizard::onCurrentIdChanged(int)
```

worked for me (in PyQt4).

This effectively hides the back button again on every wizard page, but it achieves the desired effect.

Comment: pyside2: for me the button reappears when `completeChanged` is emitted. it's not even possible to connect `hide` to `completeChanged`. only solution i found is manually call `hide` after every emit of `completeChanged` which sucks

Answer (score 5):

An alternative (maybe more framework oriented) way would be to set the QWizardPage, which comes before the page you want the back button to be disabled in, to be a commit page. Just call `this.setCommitPage(true)` on a QWizardPage and the next page wont have its back button enabled.

from [QWizardPage documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html#setCommitPage)

> *void QWizardPage::setCommitPage(bool commitPage)* Sets this page to be a commit page if commitPage is true; otherwise, sets it to be a
>   normal page. A commit page is a page that represents an action which
>   cannot be undone by clicking Back or Cancel. A Commit button replaces
>   the Next button on a commit page. Clicking this button simply calls
>   QWizard::next() just like clicking Next does.
>   **A page entered directly from a commit page has its Back button disabled.** See also isCommitPage().

If you want all the back buttons to be disabled, you could just call it on every page.