# Can't get access to wizard buttons from page

Tags: qt, qwizard

I want to disable "Back" button on the wizard page:

```
 void myPage::initializePage( void )
 {
     // ... 
     wizard()->button( QWizard::BackButton )->setDisabled( true );
 }
```

But the button stays active.
Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to completely disable or hide Back button in QWizard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072626/how-to-completely-disable-or-hide-back-button-in-qwizard)

Comment: I saw that question. it is similar but not duplicated. Because I asked why QWizard::button works in one place, and do not work in another.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko: please paste an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) compliant code.